# how to center enumerate environment in tabu?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

The following code

```
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}    
{\setlength{\tabulinesep}{3pt}

    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | m{2cm} | X[c,m] | }
        \hline
        item  & 
        item
        \\
        \hline
        test test test testtest testtest testtest testtest test & 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 11
    \item 22
    \end{enumerate}  
        \\
        \hline
    \end{tabu}
```

generate

[image]

the enumerate list is not center. How to solve this?

Comment: what you mean with "centered"? Vertically is quite well (not perfect, of course) centered, horizontally no, since enumerate obey "`X`" not `c` in column type option. If you replace `c` with `l`, you will receive the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a lists (itemize, enumerate, ..) inside the tables require that cells with list has form of mini pages.. This means that at columns of type `c`, `l` or `r` you need to encapsulate a list into mini pages, something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
some text  & \begin{minipage}{<width of minipage}
                 \begin{itemize}
             \item 11
             \item 22
                 \end{itemize}
              \end{minipage}  
\end{tabular}
```

In case, that you use columns of type `p{<width>}` or `m{<width>}`, or X (at `tabularx`, `tabu`), the encapsulation into mini pages is not necessary anymore, you can write for example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{cX}
some text  &     \begin{itemize}
             \item 11
             \item 22
                 \end{itemize}  
\end{tabularx}
```

List in mini page as well in columns of mentioned types exploit complete width of cell, regardless in case of `tabu` you have options `X[,c,m]`.

**Edit:** Here is now complete MWE, which can be copied and compiled. Also the picture of table is added.

If your list is narrower than available width of cell, than you can horizontally centered only *mini pages* in which you encapsulate list, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | m{2cm} | X[c,m] | }
        \hline
item    & item                  \\
        \hline
test test test test test test test test test test test test 
test test test test test test test test test test test test
        &   \begin{minipage}{0.25\hsize}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 11
    \item 22
    \end{enumerate}
            \end{minipage}      \\
    \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

However, in this mini page the list is left aligned:

[image]

In above MWE the `fbox` serve only for showing size and position of mini page.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But I can't run the last example properly, is there something wrong?

Comment: @user15964, maybe. Now I see that I erase width ratio and left the comma after it. Try to erase comma (only `X[c,m]`) and see if this will work. I already erase my test files, so I can not check this now. I will do this during afternoon (here, GMT).

Comment: still not working...

Comment: @user15964, I find spare time earlier and upgrade my answer with complete MWE and picture of table, which confirm my explanation in answer. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thank you. It seems that `\hsize` is the key, right? But what does it mean? I read this link, however don't understand your usage of `\hsize`. There is even a sentence says "\hsize is a TeX primitive that should not be usually used in LaTeX"

Comment: `hsize` is (simplified speaking) available horizontal space. In your case it is equal to width of tabular cell. Instead you can use an absolute measure (for example `2cm` ) or fraction of `\textwidth` etc. It is TeX primitive, in LaTeX is equivalent `\linewidth`.